# Appium, C# : how to go through a list in android

Tags: c#, android, automation, appium

I have been using Appium in C# via VisualStudio for Automation of my job's Android App.

I need to gather details from a element list in the Android App...
but Im encountering a lot of NoSuchElement exceptions because some elements are shown only halfway in view. if I do "swipe down" to make the element completely visible my list of elements found gets corrupted and is no longer pointing at the right elements... any thoughts?

here is an example of what Im facing:
I have a list of 10 elements, on the phone itself you see only 4 elements, one of the 4 , is only half shown, if I do swipe I will have to look again for the elements and build another function to tell me if the last element I saw is in the new set of elements inview now

```html
 manager.test.Log(Status.Info, "Looking for the element in question and deleting it: ");
 
            int boxsize=0;
            try
            {
                boxsize = manager.Driver.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/main_linear_layout").Size.Height;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                manager.test.Log(Status.Fail,"Failed to find Elements...");

                throw e;
            }
           
            var screensize = manager.Driver.Manage().Window.Size.Height;
            var Boxes = manager.Driver.FindElementsById("com.unionBank.app:id/main_linear_layout");

      
                for (int i=0; i < Boxes.Count; i++)
            {
                var box = Boxes[i];
                if ((box.Location.Y + boxsize) < screensize)
                {
                    elementDate = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/executed_date_text_view").Text.Replace("תאריך ביצוע: ", "");
                    elementStatus = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/status_text_view").Text.Replace("סטאטוס: ", "");
                    elementAmount = box.FindElement(GetAmountLocator(manager)).Text.Replace("₪", "").Replace(",","");
                    elementRef = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/reference_number_text_view").Text.Replace("אסמכתא: ", "") ;
                  

                    if ((elementDate.Contains(date)) && (elementStatus.Equals(status)) && (elementAmount.Contains(amount)) && (elementRef.Equals(referance)) )
                    {

                        var button = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/cancel_operation");
                        button.Click();
                        res += "\nFound the Order to cancel";
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        var  cancelBtn = manager.Driver.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/cancel_order_button");
                        cancelBtn.Click();
                        

                        manager.test.Log(Status.Pass, "Found elemnt <br/> Deleteing element <br/> Done... ");
                        res += "\nDeleted";
                        break;
                    }

                }
                else if ((box.Location.Y + boxsize) > screensize)
                {
                    var move = screensize - (box.Location.Y + boxsize - screensize);
                    manager.Driver.Swipe(0, screensize - 10, 0, move - 20, 800);

                    elementDate = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/executed_date_text_view").Text.Replace("תאריך ביצוע: ", "");
                    elementStatus = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/status_text_view").Text.Replace("סטאטוס: ", "");
                    elementAmount = box.FindElement(GetAmountLocator(manager)).Text.Replace("₪", "").Replace(",", "");
                    elementRef = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/reference_number_text_view").Text.Replace("אסמכתא: ", "");
                     

                    if ((elementDate.Contains(date)) && (elementStatus.Equals(status)) && (elementAmount.Contains(amount)) && (elementRef.Equals(referance)))
                    {

                        var button = box.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/cancel_operation");
                        button.Click();
                        res += "\nFound the Order to cancel";
                        var cancelBtn = manager.Driver.FindElementById("com.unionBank.app:id/cancel_order_button");
                        cancelBtn.Click();
                        manager.test.Log(Status.Pass, "Found elemnt <br/> Deleteing element <br/> Done... ");
                        res += "\nDeleted";
                        break;
                    }

                    var moveNext = screensize- boxsize;
                    manager.Driver.Swipe(0, screensize - 10, 0, moveNext - 10, 800);
                    Boxes = manager.Driver.FindElementsById("com.unionBank.app:id/main_linear_layout");
                    i = 1;


                }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelleg Shalom.

Your code is overly complicated and does not address your main issue, since I automate in Java and not in C# I will explain what you need to do in some simple steps:

1. Create a function called `scrollDown()` - just a function for scrolling down a bit.
2. create a function `findElementUsingScrolling(By by, int interactions)`- in this function, You only search for the element in the screen until its visible, basically what you do is->

   ```
   findElementUsingScrolling(By by, int interactions){
       if (driver.findElements(by).size() == 0){
          scrollDown(); //Element is not on screen, scroll down again
       }else { 
          return; //This means that the element is now on screen
       }
     }
   ```
3. At this point you know that "elementDate" is on screen and visible. Now you can finally interact with it and change its text.

Comment: Thank you David for replying!
from what I understand the code you suggest will help me find a list of elements when the list itself is not in view, I'll try to explain this better:
I have a list of 10 elements, on the phone itself you see only 4 elements, one of the 4 , is only half shown, if I do swipe I will have to look again for the elements and build another function to tell me if the last element I saw is in the new set of elements inview now